# How do I stop my linux desktop from freezing when I run out of RAM?

Tags: linux, memory, desktop

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with 16GB of RAM. Under normal use, my system uses about 4GB of RAM, and 0 swap (1GB configured). Every couple of days, my Firefox hits a bug and starts leaking memory extremely fast (1GB/s) until my RAM fills up.

I try to watch my RAM and kill Firefox before it's too late. But when I don't kill it in time, my system slows to a crawl and I'm unable to move my mouse. I've tried using Ctrl-Alt-F2 to switch to another terminal, but even that gets stuck after I enter my password. I'm left with no option but to forcefully power off the system and lose my desktop session.

I've read a couple of articles/StackExchange answers about disabling swap, and they all say disabling swap is a bad idea, and that I should try adjusting `vm.swappiness` instead. I set it to `5`, but that just buys me more time to kill the process manually before the system ultimately becomes unresponsive.

**How do I make my Linux desktop perform sanely (like Windows/macOS) and kill misbehaving applications before they impact desktop responsiveness?**

Comment: I think it might be easier to fix Firefox...

Comment: Few ideas: [*Limit memory usage for a single Linux process*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44985/108618).